# Patch or Mock Google Cloud Logging in Python unittests

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, python-unittest, python-mock, google-cloud-logging

I have a program which is eventually deployed on Google Cloud Platform and I use the Logs Explorer with GCP to monitor my logs. For that, I need to use the google.cloud.logging library, which is necessary to show logs with correct severity level on GCP Logs Explorer.

In my unit-tests, I am trying to patch the the call to the google.cloud.logging library, however, they all end up with 403 error on my local, suggesting that the library has not been patched.

cloud_logger.py

```
import google.cloud.logging
import logging
def get_logger():
    client = google.cloud.logging.Client()
    client.get_default_handler()
    client.setup_logging()
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    return logger
```

rss_crawler.py which utlizes the cloud_logger.get_logger

```
from cloud_logger import get_logger
logger = get_logger()
def crawl_rss_source(source_crawling_details):
    brand_name = source_crawling_details[constants.BRAND_NAME]
    source_name = source_crawling_details[constants.SOURCE_NAME]
    initial_agent_settings = source_crawling_details[constants.INITIAL_AGENT_SETTINGS]
    logger.info(f"Started crawling {brand_name}-{source_name} crawling")
    source = source_crawling_details["source"]
    entry_points_list = source[constants.ENTRY]
    source_crawling_details.update({constants.ENTRY: entry_points_list})
    source_crawling_details.update({constants.AGENT: initial_agent_settings})
    content = get_content(source_crawling_details)
    logger.info("Getting links present in rss feed entry")
    entry_points = rss_entry_points(content)
    source_crawling_details.update({constants.ENTRY_POINTS: entry_points})
    candidate_urls = start_content_tasks(source_crawling_details)
    if not candidate_urls:
        raise CustomException("There are no links to scrape")
    # filtered urls found with crawl rules, next step get scrape candidates based on scrape rules
    scrape_rules = source[constants.SCRAPE]
    scrape_candidates = get_scrape_candidates(scrape_rules, candidate_urls)
    if not scrape_candidates:
        raise CustomException(
            f"Could not find any links for scraping, please check scrape,crawl rules, or possibly depth level for brand {brand_name} , source {source_name}"
        )
    return scrape_candidates
```

test_rss_crawler.py

```
@patch("start_crawl.fetch_source_crawling_fields")
    @patch("rss_crawler.logger")
    def test_crawl_rss_source_raises_exception(
        self, mocked_logger, mocked_source_fetcher
    ):
        mocked_logger.logger.return_value = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        self.test_source[constants.SCRAPE] = {
            "white_list": ["https://buffer.com/blog/(\\w|\\d|\\-)+/$"]
        }
        details = set_content_source_details(
            self.brand_name,
            self.source_name,
            self.agent_args,
            self.source,
            **self.key_word_argument,
        )
        # test to see if exception is raised if scrape rule is not matching
        self.assertRaises(CustomException, crawl_rss_source, details)
        self.test_source[constants.CRAWL] = {"white_list": ["https://buffer.com/blog/"]}
        details = set_content_source_details(
            self.brand_name,
            self.source_name,
            self.agent_args,
            self.source,
            **self.key_word_argument,
        )
        # test to see if exception is raised if crawl rule is not matching
        self.assertRaises(CustomException, crawl_rss_source, details)
```

However, I get these warning messages, when I run these tests, even after patching:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/reydon227/Concured/crawler/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/logging_v2/handlers/transports/background_thread.py", line 115, in _safely_commit_batch
    batch.commit()
  File "/Users/reydon227/Concured/crawler/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/logging_v2/logger.py", line 385, in commit
    client.logging_api.write_entries(entries, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/reydon227/Concured/crawler/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/logging_v2/_gapic.py", line 149, in write_entries
    self._gapic_api.write_log_entries(request=request)
  File "/Users/reydon227/Concured/crawler/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/logging_v2/services/logging_service_v2/client.py", line 592, in write_log_entries
    response = rpc(request, retry=retry, timeout=timeout, metadata=metadata,)
  File "/Users/reydon227/Concured/crawler/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py", line 145, in __call__
    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/reydon227/Concured/crawler/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 286, in retry_wrapped_func
    return retry_target(
  File "/Users/reydon227/Concured/crawler/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 189, in retry_target
    return target()
  File "/Users/reydon227/Concured/crawler/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 69, in error_remapped_callable
    six.raise_from(exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc), exc)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 The caller does not have permission
```

Comment: Did you [set up Authentication](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/libraries#setting_up_authentication) for the account that is trying to run the client library?

Comment: I get these warnings while running tests, even after patching the library.

Comment: Which roles are assigned to the Account that is running the client library? Checked if the Account has the proper role assigned as per [Access control guide](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/access-control). Are you using any another GCP Service other than Cloud Logging?

Answer (score 0):

not sure about how author handled that, but I had similar symptoms with one of my tests with mocked google things, and I can't see any imports section in `test_rss_crawler.py` code. In my code I had to import class under test inside test method, because `@mock.patch(..)` runs before method, but after test file import section, and code in imported module may already initialize class supposed to be patched, so patch has no effect. Mb smbd will find useful that importing modules supposed to be patched inside test method may help.

```
@mock.patch('some_class')
def test_smth(self, some_class):
  import some_class
  some_class.return_value = ....
```